# What does 'isLocked' field in the Repository object refer to in GraphQL API?

Tags: github, github-api, github-graphql

The [GitHub GraphQL API documentation for the Repository object](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#repository) shows an `isLocked` field, which it describes with, "Indicates if the repository has been locked or not."

I can't find a reference in the GitHub documentation to "locking" a repository. How does a repository end up in a "locked" state? I do notice that isLocked is true if the repository has been transferred to a different organization, but I need to know if that is the only case, or if there are other scenarios that result in a locked repository.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is another filed in a graphQL API: lockReason (https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/graphql/reference/enums#repositorylockreason), where you can see what was the specific case (billing, migrating, moving, rename).